# Change the Icon If there is any entry in the text

Tags: angular, angular6

[Image 1 (Before entering the input)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjeGU.png)

[Image 2  (After we start entering the input)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwb5c.png)

When there is no input in the text box ,the icon is grey,but as soon as we start entering the text the icon should change to blue.

`

```
        <mat-icon svgIcon="user-icon-active" class="actvIcoCss" *ngIf="username?.length > 0" [ngStyle]="{height: '3vh', width: '2vw'}"></mat-icon>
```

```
        <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls['username'].errors && !loginForm.controls['username'].pristine" [ngStyle]="{'width':'190px','padding-left':'35px'}">
          <div class="wrnTxt">Please enter a valid Username.</div>
        </div>
        <br>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass directive to add css class when condition is met.

```
<your-element [ngClass]="{'blue-css-class': username?.length > 0 }">...</your-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

In html file:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username">
<mat-icon [ngClass]="{'active': username.length > 0}"></mat-icon>
```

Css file:

```
.active {
  color: blue
}
```

Component.ts:

```
username: string = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

In login.component.css

```
.actvIcoCss.color_ash { color: #e9ecef; }
.actvIcoCss.color_blue { color: #9CB8EF; }
```

In login.component.html

```
<mat-icon class="actvIcoCss color_ash" *ngIf="isEmpty"></mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="actvIcoCss color_blue" *ngIf="!isEmpty"></mat-icon>
```

In login.component.ts

```
isEmpty = true;
const elem = document.getElementById('username').value;
if (elem > 0 ) {
   isEmpty = false;
}
```

your input field should have an id and that id should mention in getElementById("MENTION_ID").